# AsyncTask doesn't work while progressDialog spinning

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I want to dismiss my progressdialog that started in constructor in postexecute.But postexecute can't be executed.i tried to print a message in doInBackground() method but even that wasn't printed.However it works fine when i don't show dialog.Please help,thanks.

```
public class MyJsonParser extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, List<Category>>
{

    private static final String categoriesUrl = "some_url1";
    private static final String postsUrl = "some_url2";
    private List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<Category>();
    private Context context;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private Activity activity;

    public MyJsonParser(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.activity = (Activity) context;
        pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Loading", "Please wait...");

    }

    @Override
    protected List<Category> doInBackground(Void... params)
    {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet get1 = new HttpGet(categoriesUrl);
        HttpResponse response1;

        try
        {
                        System.out.println("doInBackground");
            response1 = client.execute(get1);
            StatusLine statusLine = response1.getStatusLine();
            if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == 200)
            {
                try
                {
                    HttpEntity entity = response1.getEntity();
                    InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(content);
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
                    JsonObject jsObject = parser.parse(reader)
                            .getAsJsonObject();
                    JsonElement jsElement = jsObject.get("categories");
                    Type type = new TypeToken<List<Category>>()              {}.getType();
                    categories = gson.fromJson(jsElement, type);
                    content.close();
                } catch (JsonIOException ex)
                {
                    System.out.println("JsonIOException");
                } catch (JsonParseException ex)
                {
                    System.out.println("JsonIOException");
                }
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        for(int i=0;i<categories.size();i++)
        {
            List<Post> posts = new ArrayList<Post>();
            HttpGet get2 = new HttpGet(postsUrl+categories.get(i).getId());
            HttpResponse response2; 
          try
          {

             response2 = client.execute(get2);
             StatusLine statusLine = response2.getStatusLine();
             if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == 200)
            {
                try
                {
                    HttpEntity entity = response2.getEntity();
                    InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(content);
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
                    JsonObject jsObject = parser.parse(reader)
                            .getAsJsonObject();
                    JsonElement jsElement = jsObject.get("posts");
                    Type type = new TypeToken<List<Post>>(){}.getType();
                    posts = gson.fromJson(jsElement, type);
                    content.close();

                } catch (JsonIOException ex)
                {
                    System.out.println("JsonIOException");
                } catch (JsonParseException ex)
                {
                    System.out.println("JsonIOException");
                } 
             }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e)
            {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

              categories.get(i).setPosts(posts); 
              //publishProgress((int)progressbar.getMax()/i);
            } 

        return categories;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {

        System.out.println("onPreExecuteeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
        //activity.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        //activity.setProgress(0);
        //pDialog.setMessage("Plz wait");
        // pDialog.show();
         super.onPreExecute();
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Category> result)
    {

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, BaseContent.class);
    intent.putExtra("categories", (ArrayList<Category>) result);
    context.startActivity(intent);
    pDialog.dismiss();
        activity.finish();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

Comment: How you are starting your `MyJsonParser` task?

Comment: new MyJsonParser(MainActivity.this).execute();

Comment: So if `ProgressDialog.show` is in constructor doInBackground is not called?

Comment: no it's called,but it doesn't go inside try

Comment: I cant understand, its called  but doesn't go inside... `HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();` is called?

Comment: i can print message in doInBackground when it's called,but the message in try isn't shown,i cant understand too :)

Comment: Are you processing your `ProcessDialog` within another `AsyncTask`, so you are running 2 asynctasks at once?

Comment: no it's only one asynctask,and thanks for ur suggestions,it works now

Answer (score 0):

How about you show progress dialog in onPreExecute() instead of constructor, onPreExecute() runs in UI thread.

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{    
    System.out.println("onPreExecuteeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee");
    pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "Loading", "Please wait...");
    super.onPreExecute();
}
```

Comment: constructor called there new new MyJsonParser(MainActivity.this), anyway i tried PreExecute too,it doesn't work